# How to use iptables to prevent repeated attacks on port 80?

Tags: server, 15.10, security, iptables, firewall

There a is massive attack on port 80 on my Server i try to use iptable This way to banned attackers

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 212.252.96.128 -j DROP
```

but there are too many IPs attacking how to prevent this kind of attacks ? Is there better way To protect my Ubuntu server from getting attacked ?

Comment: `fail2ban` is what you should be looking at. It can ban IPs after a certain configurable number of unsuccessful attempts to connect.

Comment: Wiki link - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fail2ban

Comment: i try to read wiki link what is ignore ip is fore ? there is too many ips attacking my server

Comment: Yeah, kind of confusing how that's written.  `ignoreip` is the IP of the local server, it basically means, "don't block this, and ignore log entries".

Comment: i installed fail2ban and set default data to sudo nano jail.local then i save and restarted fail2ban is this every thing i have to do ?

Comment: i installed fail2ban and start it but it does not block the ips

Comment: @Vlark.Lopin, what does your /etc/fail2ban/jail.local file have in it?